# How to import line breaks (\n) in string from excel file Python

Tags: python, pandas, list, line-breaks

I'm trying to import a list of strings out of an excel file. These strings include line breaks (\n) but Python just prints them out like normal text and ignores them.
Does anyone have an idea how to make python use these linebreaks?
The excel file looks something like this:[excel file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l9XDM.png)
The test code I'm using is this:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel('quote.xlsx')
string = list(df.String)
print(len(string))

for i in range(0, len(string)):
    print(string[i])
```

But this outputs:[line breaks didn't work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/evX3a.png)

I tried using the code described earlier

Comment: Actually if you just add regular line breaks in excel they get imported, so this solves this issue. However I'd be interested why python doesn't acknowledge the "\n"

Answer (score 0):

I think that this is just how Python behaves when encountring a special (*a backslash followed by a character with a special meaning*), it treats it as an escape sequence and so adds a backslash (`\`).

```
df.loc[0, "String"] # returns 'Test\\nTest'
```

What I see as a workaround is to use the `converters` parameter in [`read_excel`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html) :

```
df = pd.read_excel("quote.xlsx", converters={"String": lambda x: x.replace("\\n", "\n")})
​
string = list(df["String"])
```

Ouput :

```
for i in range(0, len(string)):
    print(string[i])
​
2
Test
Test
Test2
Test2
```